# Animated series from 80s or 90s involving Space ships and an orange tree farm in a canyon

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space, cartoon

I am looking for the name of a sci-fi cartoon.

#### Key plot points

1. There were Space ships flown by some American voiced crew.
2. They were some kind of rescue squad or maybe space police.
3. In one episode they went to an orange tree farm in a canyon which used mirrors on the canyon walls to direct sunlight to the oranges.
4. They had a force field that protected the canyon but some bad guys came and shot the mirrors.
5. The heroes came back and saved the day.
6. Another episode was set in an underground ancient tomb of some kind that was covered by a sandstorm once they escaped.

#### Chronology and other relevant information

It had kind of 80s or 90s animation.

I don't think I ever saw it on TV. I only ever watched the same 3 episodes on VHS.

Comment: StarCom: The US Space Force!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1 I found it here.
http://geekculture.co/its-time-for-these-9-toys-and-cartoons-from-the-1980s-to-stage-a-comeback/

Comment: @Jonny Well done. Self answers are very welcome here.

Comment: Thanks for editing the post. I'm loving the site. I will know where to come next time! Aparently the show wasnt super popular but the episodes are on youtube so i will be watching them tonight im sure!
Thanks again !

Answer (score 5):

Since the OP has elected not to self-answer..I'll do it for him.

This is [**StarCom: The U.S. Space Force**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0129398/)

[image]

Wikipedia:

> Starcom: The U.S. Space Force is a 1987 animated syndicated U.S. television series inspired by a motorized toy franchise manufactured by Coleco. It was produced by DiC Enterprises and distributed by Coca-Cola Telecommunications. The plot detailed the adventures of an American astronaut brigade as they fought off attempted invasions by Shadow Force, a nasty collection of aliens and robots led by the nefarious Emperor Dark. The toy line was popular in Europe and Asia, but was unsuccessful in the North American domestic market.

---

> Young hero Col. James “Dash” Derringer, an ace Starcom pilot, was the star of the series, and several of his teammates were family members. He was also backed up by the resourceful ace pilot John “Slim” Griffin, whose niece was yet another Starcom pilot. Other heroes on the Starcom side included Col. Paul “Crowbar” Corbin and Admiral Franklin Brinkley

[**Source**](http://en.series-tv-shows.com/starcom-the-u-s-space-force/)